# C++ open разных файлов, возвращает одинаковый дескриптор

Tags: c++, linux, c, port

Здравствуйте, пытаюсь в линуксе перечислить доступные порты.
Находит два, но при этом почему то возвращает одинаковые дескрипторы, хотя программа не закрывает файлы.

```
printf("Ports enumeration: \n");

    int portDesc;                   
    std::string pathBasis = "/dev/ttyS";
    for (uint counter = 0; counter <= 64; counter++)
    {
        std::string searchString = pathBasis;
        searchString += std::to_string(counter);
        portDesc = open(searchString.c_str(), O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
        if (portDesc != -1)
        {
            printf("%s%s%s%x%s","Found serial port: ", searchString.c_str(), "\nPort descriptor: ", std::to_string(portDesc), "\n");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Интересное у вас решение, работает? Даже если и так, лучше всё-таки через udev это делать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам надо заменить строчку

```
printf("%s%s%s%x%s","Found serial port: ", searchString.c_str(), "\nPort descriptor: ", std::to_string(portDesc), "\n");
```

на

```
printf("%s%s%s%x%s","Found serial port: ", searchString.c_str(), "\nPort descriptor: ", portDesc, "\n");
```

Потому как вы преобразовываете дескриптор в строку, а потом зачем-то выводите ее как целое шестнадцатеричное число (формат %x) - вот в этом косяк. У вас выводится не дескриптор - а не понятно что.

А еще лучше - на

```
printf("Found serial port: %s\nPort descriptor: %x\n", searchString.c_str(), portDesc);
```

А еще лучше - юзать потоки ввода-вывода стандартной библиотеки, чтобы так не попадать.